# ASP.NET MVC : dropdown positioning and save

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("LookupTypeImmobilier", new SelectList(Model.LkpTypeImmobilier, "Code", "Value", Model.LookupTypeImmobilier.Code))
```

The lookup class has the properties : *Id, FR, NL*, *Value* and *Code*. The *Value* is text show in the dropdown.

*LkpTypeImmobilier* is the list and *LookupTypeImmobilier* is the selected, the values are correct (see the pictures) but the dropdown is not setted.

When I select and I post like this :

```
var jqxhr = $.post("Controller/Action", $("form").serialize(),
function (data) {
});
```

The values coming from textbox, textarea are posted and I get them in the controller but not the dropdown.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

**Update 1** (ShankarSangoli request)

```
<select id="LookupTypeImmobilier" name="LookupTypeImmobilier"><option value="0">----</option>
<option value="1">habitation principale / logement familial</option>
<option value="2">résidence secondaire</option>
<option value="3">immeuble de rapport</option>
<option value="4">terrain à bâtir</option>
<option value="5">terre agricole</option>
<option value="6">bois</option>
</select>
```

**Update 2**
Tried with this but not work (null when I post and no positioning)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LookupTypeImmobilier, new SelectList(Model.LkpTypeImmobilier, "Code", "Value", Model.LookupTypeImmobilier))
```

**Update 3**

No solution then I use a workaround. I post with jQuery field by field and not the model. In edition I set the dropdown list position by jQuery. It's really not the right way but work, I hope find a solution.

Comment: What is the html rendered on the page for that code, can you check?

Comment: mmmmhhh I have to use a DropDownListFor I think

Comment: that is better option but this should work as well

Comment: The markup looks perfect it should work fine. Can you select any option other than the default "---" and then try to submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.LookupTypeImmobilier, 
    new SelectList(Model.LkpTypeImmobilier, "Code", "Value")
)
```

Now in order to set a default value for the dropdownlist ensure that your controller action sets a value of the `LookupTypeImmobilier` on the view model:

```
var model = new MyViewModel
{
    // Preselect the third element which in the rendered HTML has value="3"
    LookupTypeImmobilier = "3",
    LkpTypeImmobilier = ...
}
return View(model);
```

Make sure that the value you are setting the `LookupTypeImmobilier` property to exists in the `LkpTypeImmobilier` collection. This will automatically preselect the corresponding element of the dropdownlist. And it should correspond to the `Code` property, **not** the `Value`.

As far as getting the selected value back in your POST controller action is concerned, simply use this same view model as action argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.LookupTypeImmobilier will contain the selected value here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just tried, shoud work but not work. When I save the form, in the controller null for the dropdown (textbox, textarea, checkbox are ok). When I edit a element no dropdown positioning (textbox, textarea, checkbox are ok)

Answer (score 0):

Explain please, "The lookup class has the properties : Id, FR, NL, Value and Code", but your view has @Html.DropDownList("LookupTypeImmobilier"...

can you write something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Value,new SelectList(/**/))
```

Sorry, maybe I understand something wrong :)

Comment: To be clear, I use NHibernate, the database (and then the class) has these fields but binded with the dropdown list it's "Code" and "Value"

Comment: can you look in firebug which data goes to your action. I think your selected value will have name 'LookupTypeImmobilier'. Right?